# Remove Visual Studio but keep C++ Compiler

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Community 2013. Now I would like to remove VS but keep the MSVC++ compiler as I am using QtCreator. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading the separate installer file for MSVC++ and install it after you uninstalled VS. Technically, the VS Uninstaller will also remove the MSVC++ program.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is not at this time any way to install just the Visual C++ toolset.